# How to use JsonSerializer to deserialize a heterogenous JSON Array?

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

Consider the following class:

```cs
class MethodCallDescription
{
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
    public object[] MethodParameters { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to deserialize the following JSON into an instance of that class:

```json
{
    "MethodName": "LaunchRockets",
    "MethodParameters": [ "Long Range", 100, true ]
}
```

It seems that when I do this, `MethodParameters` becomes an array containing objects of type `JsonElement`, and not string, int, and bool.

How can I tell JsonSerializer to turn `MethodParameters` into an array containing values of the expected types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across [this test](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/81bf79fd9aa75305e55abe2f7e9ef3f60624a3a1/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/tests/Serialization/CustomConverterTests.Object.cs#L316) in the System.Text.Json source code which uses a custom `JsonConverter` to mimic Newtonsoft.Json behavior for object deserialization (which does maintain the original object type instead).

Here's a slimmed down version of that custom converter that could be used to achieve this:

```
class SystemObjectNewtonsoftCompatibleConverter : JsonConverter<object>
{
    public override object Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return reader.TokenType switch
        {
            JsonTokenType.True => true,
            JsonTokenType.False => false,
            JsonTokenType.Number => reader.GetInt32(),
            JsonTokenType.String => reader.GetString(),
            _ => Fallback(ref reader)
        };

        object Fallback(ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
        {
            // Use JsonElement as fallback.
            // Newtonsoft uses JArray or JObject.
            using JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
            return document.RootElement.Clone();
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Should not get here.");
}
```

---

This example using that converter shows the object types being preserved:

```
const string json = @"{
    ""MethodName"": ""LaunchRockets"",
    ""MethodParameters"": [ ""Long Range"", 100, true ]
}";

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new SystemObjectNewtonsoftCompatibleConverter());
MethodCallDescription instance = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MethodCallDescription>(json, options);
Console.WriteLine(instance.MethodName);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", instance.MethodParameters.Select(p => (p, p.GetType().Name))));
```

Giving the ouput:

```
LaunchRockets
(Long Range, String), (100, Int32), (True, Boolean)
```